# Unable to set default value for dynamically generated select dropdown in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
<select className="form-control"
    placeholder="Category name"
    name="category"
    value={course.category}
    onChange={handleChange}>
    {categories.map((category) => <option key={category._id} data-id={category._id}>{category.categoryName}</option>)}
</select>
```

Setting default value:

```
const handleCourseSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setCourse((prevState) => {
        return { ...prevState, category: categories[0].categoryName }
    })
    console.log('create.js:: handleCourseSubmit:: data: ', course.category); //prints empty string created from initial state
}
```

How do I set default value on submit?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
    const [course, setCourse] = useState({
        category: '', // Initial category value
        // ... other state properties
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Updated category:', course.category);
    }, [course.category]);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        // Handle change logic here
    };

    const handleCourseSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCourse((prevState) => {
            return { ...prevState, category: categories[0].categoryName };
        });
    };

    // Render your component
}
```

> ```
>     Logging inside the callback function:
> ```

```
const handleCourseSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setCourse((prevState) => {
        console.log('Updated category:', prevState.category);
        return { ...prevState, category: categories[0].categoryName };
    });
};
```

Comment: Did not work...